# Remove headline from title page in Quarto beamer presentation for Szeged theme

Tags: quarto, beamer

How can I remove the headline in a Quarto beamer presentation when using the Szeged theme?

I tried various approaches to remove the headline, such as [creating a special frame option](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/563438/beamer-how-to-add-a-new-option-for-the-frame-environment) (which unfortunately removed the headline also for the following two slides). As far as I know in Quarto I cannot create a new environment around a frame [as suggested in this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44983/beamer-removing-headline-and-its-space-on-a-single-frame-for-plan-but-keepin) and `\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}` does not do anything when it's declared inside `\defbeamertemplate*{title page}`.

```
---
title: "My Presentation"
format: 
  beamer:
    theme: Szeged
    include-in-header:
      text: |
        \defbeamertemplate*{title page}{customized}[1][]
        {
          \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
          \def\beamer@entrycode{\vspace*{-\headheight}}
          \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par
        }
editor: visual
---

# Quarto

Some text.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ditch the automatically added title page, you can add one yourself and e.g. select a plain frame which does not have a headline:

```
---
format: 
  beamer:
    theme: Szeged
    include-in-header:
      text: |
        \defbeamertemplate*{title page}{customized}[1][]
        {
          \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
          \def\beamer@entrycode{\vspace*{-\headheight}}
          \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par
        }
editor: visual
header-includes:
- \AtBeginDocument{\title{My Presentation}\begin{frame}[plain]\titlepage\end{frame}}
---

# Quarto

Some text.
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I got confused with `include-in-header:` and `header-includes:`. May I ask what the difference between those two is?

Comment: @xyz You're welcome! No idea if and what is the difference, I'm not a quarto user and only know the `header-includes` key and then do everything else with latex code